# How to extract statistics from Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to extract a list of all dead people in Wikipedia and compare their ages when they died. All dead people in Wikipedia has the following fields filled:

```
| birth_name = Thomas Alva Edison
| birth_date = {{birth date|mf=yes|1847|02|11}}
| death_date ={{death date and age|mf=yes|1931|10|18|1847|02|11}}
```

I will have to make a crawler? There is anything in the Wikipedia API that can help me?
Is there any place where I can start to crawl? Any list of dead people?

Comment: I found starting pages for my crawler. They can be similar to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1898_deaths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a dump of all the contents of Wikipedia available for download here:

http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/

The file is an `.xml` file of several gigabytes in size, and contains the text of all the pages on Wikipedia (amongst other things). How you process this depends on what programming language you're going to use.

Comment: That's one alternative. But I think I can get the crawler working faster than downloading and parsing this file.

Comment: Ah, now that you've mentioned that you have starting pages for the crawler, there probably is a faster method.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) is for - all the structured data from Wikipedia in a database. Try the following query at http://dbpedia.org/sparql :

```
select distinct ?p, ?d where {
  ?p a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
  ?p <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate> ?d .
}
```